# Convert array to multidimensional hash

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl, hashtable

My task is convert array, containing hash with `x` keys to `x-1` dimensional hash.

Example:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $arr = [
    {
        'source' => 'source1',
        'group'  => 'group1',
        'param'  => 'prm1',
        'value'  => 1,
    },
    {
        'source' => 'source1',
        'group'  => 'group1',
        'param'  => 'prm2',
        'value'  => 2,
    },
];


my $res;
for my $i (@$arr) {
    $res->{ $i->{source} }                               = {};
    $res->{ $i->{source} }{ $i->{group} }                = {};
    $res->{ $i->{source} }{ $i->{group} }{ $i->{param} } = $i->{value};
}
warn Dumper $res;

my $res_expected = {
    'source1' => {
        'group1' => {
            'prm1' => 1,  # wasn't added, why ?
            'prm2' => 2
        }
    }
};
```

However it doesn't work as expected, `'prm1' => 1` wasn't added. What is wrong and how to solve this task ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are assigning to the source even if something was there, and you lose it.  Just do a `||=` instead of `=` and you'll be fine.

Or even easier, just use the fact that Perl autovivifies and leave that out.

```
my $res;
for my $i (@$arr) {
    $res->{ $i->{source} }{ $i->{group} }{ $i->{param} } = $i->{value};
}
warn Dumper $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 lines in the `for` loop are what is causing your problem. They assign a new hash reference each iteration of the loop (and erase what was entered in the previous iteration). In perl, there is no need to set a reference as you did. Just eliminate the first 2 lines and your data structure will be as you wish.

The method you chose only shows `'prmt' => 2` because that was the last item entered.